# How to efficiently copy istringstream?

Tags: c++, stl

Or ostringstream?

```
istringstream a("asd");
istringstream b = a; // This does not work.
```

I guess memcpy won't work either.

Comment: Why do you want to close this question ?

Comment: I wonder too, comments anyone?

Comment: I think it is a valid question too :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
istringstream a("asd");
istringstream b(a.str());
```

Edit:
Based on your comment to the other reply, it sounds like you may also want to copy the entire contents of an fstream into a strinstream. You don't want/have to do that one character at a time either (and you're right -- that usually is pretty slow).

```
// create fstream to read from
std::ifstream input("whatever");

// create stringstream to read the data into
std::istringstream buffer;

// read the whole fstream into the stringstream:
buffer << input.rdbuf();
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know there is an overloading for buffers!

Comment: Yeah, it's one of those cute little tricks that almost nobody knows about. Not useful all that often, but when you want what it does, it makes things quite a bit simpler.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `ostringstream` instead of `istringstream`?

Answer (score 2):

You can't just copy streams, you have to copy their buffers using iterators. For example:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
......
std::stringstream first, second;
.....
std::istreambuf_iterator<char> begf(first), endf;
std::ostreambuf_iterator<char> begs(second);
std::copy(begf, endf, begs);
```

Comment: Isn't copying one character at a time slow?

Comment: I measured it when input was a file ifstringstream. The difference was tremendous.

Comment: There is nothing called ifstringstream in C++. Could you post the code you wrote?

Comment: Why would you copy the contents of fstream into stringstream?